# Change ruler color (vertical line) in JupyterLab

Tags: codemirror, jupyter-lab

Is there any options to set the color (and style) of the Ruler CodeMirror feature in JupayterLab? Ruler column numbers can be set easily. I am wondering similar possibility exist for color (and style) of each ruler.
I use JupyterLab 2.1.0!